# Jodit React Text Editor Theming Issue

Tags: reactjs, themes, jodit

I am using a text editor npm package named jodit-react. I want to use my own customize theme. But I can't getting proper documentation for using the custom theme. Anyone used custom theme on this package?

I am only able to use dark and light theme of that package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.